# Facebook share shows advertisement banner

Tags: facebook, web, ads

When I share my website link on Facebook, I always see my own advertisement banners (of other companys)

How to show my own logo?

Website: www.zoekeenleven.be
Share example
[image: Share example]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In **OG** meta tags, add your website default logo image.

```
<meta property="og:image" content="<Image Url>" />
```